# Str.split question, need to find length of each component in a string

Tags: python

`str_list = ["hello", "", "goodbye", "wonderful", "I love Python"]`

I need to print out the length of each component of the string via `str.split`. Would be very grateful if anybody'll help

Comment: do you need the no. of character or no. of words present in the string?

Comment: I need it to print out the number of characters in each component, it being 5,0,7 etc.

Answer (score 8):

After splitting the sentence into words/phrases (which you already did), simply loop through it:

```
for i in str_list:
    print(len(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension like so,

```
[print(len(text)) for text in str_list]
```

And output is,

```
5
0
7
9
13
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the length of each word in each string, you can do:

```
str_list = ["hello", "", "goodbye", "wonderful", "I love Python"]
lengths = [[len(word) for word in my_string.split()] for my_string in str_list]
print(str_list)
print(lengths)
```

Result:

```
['hello', '', 'goodbye', 'wonderful', 'I love Python']
[[5], [], [7], [9], [1, 4, 6]]
```